# Java if and else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to make a simple text adventure game in Java and when I type Quit it ends the game. But instead it will ask if you want to do the quest even if you type quit which is suppose to end the code, I tried using loops to fix this error but had to luck. Any idea where I went wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class TextGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Boolean run = true;
        //while (run){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("~SPECTRE~");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please Choose One Below");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("New");
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.out.println("");

        String option;
        System.out.print("Select one of the options here: ");
        option = in .next();

        if (option.equals("New")) {
            System.out.println("Hello adventurer! Welcome to the land of Spectre.");

            String name;
            System.out.print("What is your name adventurer? ");
            name = in .next();
            System.out.println("Hello there! " + name);
        } else if (option.equals("Quit")) {
            System.out.println("*Returns to desktop*");
        }

        String quest;
        System.out.print("Would you like to go on a quest? ");
        quest = in .next();

        if (quest.equals("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Here is a list of quests that I would like you to do ");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("1) Fight the evil troll of Port Howlham");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("2) Deliver supplys to the soliders in need");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("3) Find the Kings lost son");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("4) Find the Gemstone of Darlingbee to defeat the evil witch of Hobbitstone");

        } else {
            option.equals("");
            System.out.println("*Please pick New Game or Quit*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course a program will continue processing instructions unless it has an instruction to stop.

Comment: I know that, but I didn't the code to do so since i'm new to Java.

Comment: It's just the way you asked the question--as if the program would terminate without being instructed to do so. So I felt the need to point out this fact since you'd be surprised the things some people don't have an understanding of. ; )

Comment: Ah yeah. I see what you mean. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
} else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Or this:

```
} else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I never knew this. Thanks for your help. Since i'm new to Java I really appreciate your help,

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking to exit the program. Use `System.exit(0);`

```
 else if(option.equals("Quit"))
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The `0` argument is a status code that indicates normal termination of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`System.exit(code)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) to finish the program. Put this at the end of the `else if` block:

```
if (option.equals("Quit") {
    ...
    System.exit(0);
}
```

The `code` can be any integer:

> The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.